# Heroku 'redirected to' in log doesn't match the URL that it actually redirects to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, heroku

I've just deployed my Ruby app to Heroku and the redirect_to in my contacts_controller.rb no longer works. If I run the local server, it works fine but on Heroku, it takes me to a URL that doesn't exist so I get an error message.

I've had a look at the Heroku log and even there, it says it's redirecting to the correct URL but that doesn't match what it does in the app.

I've tried restarting Heroku. I've searched through the documentation to see if there is a way to manually change the path because I noticed at one point in the log, it says it's pushing to '/contacts' which is the incorrect URL that gives me the error but I now think that's referencing the db, not the redirect URL.

What's odd is the redirect_to path is the same for success or failure in my if/else method and it works fine for the failure but not success.

contacts_controller.rb file:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
      if @contact.save
        redirect_to new_contact_path
        name = params[:contact][:name]
        email = params[:contact][:email]
        body = params[:contact][:comments]
        ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver
        flash[:success] = "Message sent."

      else 
        flash[:danger] = @contact.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
        redirect_to new_contact_path
      end
  end    

  private
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
    end
end
```

Here's the heroku log once I've submitted my contact form:

```
2017-03-02T12:15:00.498443+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.498389 #4]  INFO -- : [] Redirected to https://myapp.herokuapp.com/contact-us
2017-03-02T12:15:00.506175+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.506104 #4]  INFO -- : []   Rendering contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb
2017-03-02T12:15:00.506925+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.506848 #4]  INFO -- : []   Rendered contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb (0.6ms)
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793142+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.793082 #4]  INFO -- : [] Sent mail to xxxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx (6.6ms)
2017-03-02T12:15:00.786369+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.786255 #4] DEBUG -- : [] ContactMailer#contact_email: processed outbound mail in 286.1ms
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793195+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.793141 #4] DEBUG -- : [] Date: Thu, 02 Mar 2017 12:15:00 +0000
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793197+00:00 app[web.1]: From: is
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793197+00:00 app[web.1]: To: xxxxx@xxx.xxx
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793198+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <xxxx.mail>
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793199+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: Contact Form Message
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793200+00:00 app[web.1]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793200+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/html;
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793201+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793201+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793202+00:00 app[web.1]: <!DOCTYPE html>
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793202+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793203+00:00 app[web.1]: <html>
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793204+00:00 app[web.1]:   <head></head>
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793204+00:00 app[web.1]:   <body>
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793205+00:00 app[web.1]:     <p>You have received a message from the site's contact form, from 
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793206+00:00 app[web.1]:     this, is.</p>
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793207+00:00 app[web.1]:     <p>frustrating</p>
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793208+00:00 app[web.1]:   </body>
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793208+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793409+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.793333 #4]  INFO -- : [] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 305ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793869+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.793819 #4] FATAL -- : []   
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793910+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.793871 #4] FATAL -- : [] Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793958+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.793909 #4] FATAL -- : []   
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793979+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.793943 #4] FATAL -- : [] app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:13:in `create'
2017-03-02T12:15:00.794339+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/contacts" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=25154829-90fe-44c4-a715-eaf9a6fd83d1 fwd="87.114.208.14" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=313ms status=500 bytes=1669
```

And the actual link that it redirects me to is https://myapp.herokuapp.com/contacts

Error message on screen: "We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

I have a feeling it might be something to do with my db but I have no idea why it's redirecting to that link. The db that I've migrated to Heroku is called 'contacts'

Really appreciate any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Ok, that's useful to know, thanks. Yes I'm using MailGun but I'm not sure the activation worked as it should. I had to get an activation code when setting myself up as a recipient and it changed to active but when I check the heroku site and go into MailGun, it still says 'please activate your account' at the top? I temporarily removed the code in the environment.rb file but I got the same error message either way. The code is back in there now too and it still won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be with email delivery, not redirecting. If you take a look again at your log, you will see the following lines:

```
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793409+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.793333 #4]  INFO -- : [] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 305ms (ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793869+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.793819 #4] FATAL -- : []   
2017-03-02T12:15:00.793910+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-03-02T12:15:00.793871 #4] FATAL -- : [] Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):
```

Your application is returning a `500` error, and the error message shown in the log indicates an issue with email delivery (email via SMTP uses port 25).

Do you have an email add-on installed and configured for your Heroku account and attached to your app? There are several listed on Heroku's website: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/categories/email-sms

I suspect this is working as intended locally because you are running software such as `postfix`, but this is not present on Heroku out-of-the-box.